# FreeRTOS crash only in Release

Tags: c++, c, freertos

I have this code that crash only in Release:

```
int main() 
{
  MyStruct s;
  s.field = bla;

  xTaskCreate(TestTask, "TestTask", 2000, &s, 1, 0);

  // other tasks creation
  vTaskStartScheduler();
}


void TestTask(void *p) 
{
  // some delay
  MyStruct* s = (MyStruct*)p;
  another_func(s->field); // hard fault
}
```

I manage to fix it like this:

```
int main()
{
  MyStruct* s = new MyStruct();
  s->field = bla;
  xTaskCreate(TestTask, "TestTask", 2000, s, 1, 0);

  // other tasks creation
  vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

I don't understand why. Did I fixed it or workaround a memory corruption that can still be there?

Thanks.

Comment: Release is set at "-O1" if it helps

Comment: You fix it using `new`? Then tag the question as C++

Comment: If I undertand the documentation corectly then `xTaskCreate` does not block and returns after creating the task. Then `main` is exited and now `MyStruct s;`, which was on the stack of `main` doesn't exist anymore. I also wonder what happens when `main` is exited as normally the program now ends.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie normally, there is a `vTaskStartScheduler()` function that needs to be called in the main after creating the tasks, not really sure if this is the missing point.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : I should have mentioned that main does not exist, I've stripped out the code to only show how I'm passing the struct, sorry

Comment: @MikevanDyke: yes exactly, I'll edit my code

Answer (score 3):

I'm so stupid, it's written on FreeRTOS' doc:
https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html

> so it is not valid to pass the address of a stack variable.

Comment: hmm, but the variable should still exist when the task is executing, since the stack frame of the main function is the last one to be exited?

Comment: It's what we though :-/